# Mock a module property

Tags: python, mocking, pytest

I'm trying to mock a property which is at the module root:

`some_module.py`

```
@property
def conn(self):
    if not get_request():
        raise SomeError(
            "Some error happened"
        )
    return get_request().connection


Database.conn = conn
```

I've tried many different ways like:

```
@mock.patch("some_module.conn")
def test_some_test(mock_conn):
    mock_conn.return_value = mock.Mock()
```

..

```
@mock.patch("some_module.conn", new_callable=PropertyMock)
def test_some_test(mock_conn):
    mock_conn.return_value = mock.Mock()
```

..

```
@mock.patch("some_module.conn", new_callable=PropertyMock, return_value=mock.Mock())
def test_some_test():
    ...
```

But I wasn't successful. I know that some of those approaches would work if the property was belong to a class like this:

```
MyClass:
    @property
    def conn(self):
        if not get_request():
            raise SomeError(
                "Some error happened"
            )
        return get_request().connection
```

but in my case the property has to be in module's root and now I'm struggling with mocking it. Anyone has any idea how to mock that?

**Update**:

Considering `conn` as a variable and trying to mock it like a global variable didn't work either:

```
@mock.patch("some_module.conn", mock.Mock())
def test_some_test():
    ...
```

Comment: The property *is* accessible via `Database.conn`, and any code you want to test that uses it is almost certainly using `Database.conn` to access the property, not the name `some_module.conn`.

Comment: The only difference between `@property def conn(): ...; Database.conn = ...` and `class Database: @property def conn(): ...` is that the former leaves `conn` as a module-level global. The class itself behaves the same in either situation. The module itself doesn't really "have" a property in the sense that classes do.

Comment: @chepner I can't mock `Database.conn` because before code reaches that point, it will throw `SomeError` exception cuz `get_request()` is always `None` during tests and I couldn't mock it inside the property.

Comment: What is `get_request`, and why isn't it a callable value by the time you try to use the property? How `Database.conn` gets defined seems irrelevant.

Comment: @chepner It's a FastAPI progect and`get_request` will get the current API Request object where it's unavailable to get that object.

Comment: That's probably what your question should focus on. Where the property is defined seems irrelevant. `Database` only cares that it has a `property`-valued attribute named `conn`, and the assignment `Database.conn = conn` does that just as well as moving the definition inside the class statement.